# How to uninstall kingroot

Tags: root-access, uninstallation, unrooting, sony-xperia-z

I recently rooted my Sony Xpera Z Ultra (Android Version 5.0.1)using kingroot but when i restarted my phone it got unrooted again, now the only app that has root access is kingroot itself (it has a option to uninstall system apps which is working). I tried 'uninstall root' option but it didn't work. So is there any way i can uninstall kingroot app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove KINGroot?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170254/how-to-remove-kingroot)

Answer (score 0):

Go install the app "supersume" and run it. It will remove kingroot and install the real supersu from chainfire and you will have real solid root access. You may have to reroot running the kingroot app again first and immediately open and run supersume as fast as you can before the system can plug up kingroots security breach ..of that doesn't work I would find the stock firmware and flash it back to stock

Comment: You mean, install this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=darkslide.com.supersumepro