# How to remove KINGroot?

Tags: rooting, root-access, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I installed KINGroot and regretted it. Now I can't remove all of its files because of permissions only KINGroot has. My friend tried to remove it by using towelroot and other methods but my phone crashes them. I need a PC method to remove all KINGroot files but also having my phone permanently rooted. The friend I mentioned and my other friend have rooted phones without KINGroot.

Can you please help me solve this issue.

I have:

- Samsung Galaxy S3 mini - model number: GT - I8190
- version 4.1.2
- Phone manufacturing date: Jul 28 2013

If you require any other information about my phone please let me know. I messed up.

Comment: Have you tried installing [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) and using it to replace your `su` binary?  If that works then you could easily use a root file browser or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), etc. to remove the Kingroot app.  Otherwise, is reflashing the ROM an option?

Comment: @MatthewRead Kingroot uses a slightly tweaked SU binary to stop access from other SU managers. That, and newer versions will sometimes delete all traces of SuperSU from the system, then monitor it as a threat. Kingroot also shows many a privacy risks, along with some real shady dealings.

Comment: @DanBrown "Kingroot also shows many a privacy risks, along with some real shady dealings" - can you link any source supporting this?

Comment: There was a report somewhere that Kingroot was taking SIM-based information and selling it. I'll let you know if I find said article. I do know that it's an app that A) Leaves imprints, and B) kicks SuperSU to death. Why would anyone block SuperSU? It does also install other apps, although they promise it's just their system cleaning app (which I know most people do not like.)

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny Above, and here's the link I mentioned - [KingRoot still is stealing your IMEI - XDA](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/kingo-root-steals-imei-t3268525&ved=0ahUKEwicpJHjscbSAhXiCsAKHX_fBU8QFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNHA73-O2uPDjwhyyj2V74EHlGBNbA&sig2=eZfH9KSqJTzVXOft1ZJ2QA) and it's also a battery hog.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, soon after uninstalling KingRoot be sure to get another **SU management app**, to protect your device against malicious attacks since it has elevated privileges than a non rooted device,

A checklist just in case;

- Check if KingRoot is enabled as **device administrator** (under settings≥security), sometimes it's difficult to uninstall apps with such privileges
- Try to uninstall the app from  within itself, rather than dragging to uninstall (you will need to reinstall su binaries with this method, but if your goal is to just get rid of KingRoot for another SU app it's worth a go)
- Navigate directly to /system/app/ and search for a package with name com.kingroot.kinguser and delete the contents.

If the app is still stubborn, then try the PC method

Connect your device via  USB with debugging enabled,

On your PC open ADB terminal and type the codes one by one

```
# mount -o rw, remount /system

# am kill com.kingroot.kinguser

# pm uninstall com.kingroot.kinguser
```

Check if the app is removed

Comment: If no PC you could try using terminal, grant it superuser access and type pm uninstall com.kingroot.kinguser. Also a thread from xda-developers mentions a a way to replace KingRoot with SuperSU but haven't checked it myself. It's found at: https://forum.xda-developers.com/a310/general/how-to-remove-replace-kingroot-kinguser-t3308989

Comment: That would be SuperSUME. It's paid, so dot forget that :)

Comment: When I try that that it gives me `Error: java.lang.SecurityException: deletePackage operation deny`

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis looks like its not giving you permissions to do so, probably root is broken , or check the file manager you used has been granted root rights

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis Please check here: [rm failed, Operation not permitted on Rooted Android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33890752) may help solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have done:
TWRP install superSu alongside Kingroot, then install an root app unistaller and delete the Kingroot app.
Restart and should be SU instead of Kingroot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove it without PC.
I made a tool that will do this thing.
Replace it with SuperSU from https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/2020-replace-kingroot-v5-x-or-kingo-root-with-supersu.3904880/
Which works with newer versions of KingRoot too.